# Can't balance differential amplifier circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm trying to build a circuit which involves an  Op Amp in differential amplifier configuration. 
 However I've been having difficulty balancing my output. My understanding of the differential amplifier is that if configured such that R1 = R2 = Rf = Rg then Vout should be about 0 volts except I'm always getting about 0.5-0.8 volts.

I've currently set it up so that there are 5 volts going directly into R1 and R2 with all my resistors equal to 10K ohms and still I'm getting about 0.63 volts. These are diagrams of my circuit I made:

[image: Circuit schematic]

[image: Circuit fritzing]

Please also ignore the dashed lines.

This is what I was trying to build:

[image: Differential Op Amp]

Edit: Original Circuit

[image: Original circuit]

Comment: I suspect you're seeing inaccuracies in your resistor values. EDIT: never mind, that wouldn't be this significant. @stowoda has the right idea.

Comment: The Opamp will not go to 0 V if you have an unsymmetrical supply. Keep that in mind. There is also some offset error in an ideal Opamp.

Comment: I've checked and re-checked the resistor values using a bridge (same voltage drops) and I'm not sure what you mean by unsymmetrical supply (R1 and R2 receive 5V each)

Comment: You are supplying the Opamp with +5 V. This is unsymmetrical. If you would supply it with -5 V to + 5 V that would be called symmetrical. Another hint to what I have stated above: Figure 11 (Output Characteristics Current Sinking). Have a look for that in the Opamp's datasheet (I guess yours is LM358)

Comment: Should I invert one of the inputs via another Op Amp configuration?

Comment: Please have a look at the datasheet and figure 11 in particular. The Opamp will not go down to 0 V. You can get down to 20 mV if the Opamp sinks 2 µA (plz. see the referenced figure 11 from the mentioned datasheet). The Opamp's output stage consists of a totem pole structure, each of the transistors in that structure will always have same finite resistance. If you really need 0 V on the output (which I doubt) you need symmetrical supply. Then the output stage is able to go to 0 V.

Comment: Thanks, my op amp is an LM324A (the one I used in fritzing was the most similar Op Amp in the program) but I'm checking the data sheet as you say. If I understand correctly if I want to minimize the output voltage I need to use larger resistors to reduce the current into the sink range?

Comment: You've got the supply lines to your op-amp connected backwards in your diagram. But your comments suggest that you're not actually using that opamp or even that circuit... VTC as unclear what you're asking since you're not telling us what you're actually doing.

Comment: I'm pretty new at this and thought that isolating the op amp would have been a better way to troubleshoot. But how are the supply lines connected backwards?

Comment: LM32A behaves pretty the same concerning Vo_low. It's datasheet depicts that also in figure 11 (coincidentially same numeration). I would suggest you stay away from the bottom rail since the Opamp will get nonlinear there anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your advice although if I may ask: 1. what's a bottom rail, 2. what do you think would be the best way to 0 the output? E.g. should I be looking at a bipolar supply instead? My original circuit uses a wheatstone bridge - would that be adequate?

Comment: For the record, you're asking for help with a *differential amplifier* that was built with an op amp.  a *differential op amp* is something else.

Comment: @ScottSeidman - I'm a bit confused, which one of those is which?

Comment: By rail I mean suppl rail. For example: upper or top rail +5 V, lower or bottom rail 0 V. Another example: top rail + 5 V, bottom rail - 5 V. If you really want 0 V at the output when V+ and V- are the same then you will need bipolar supply and also some sort of offset compensation. Since you already have a MCU you should compensate in software though. May I ask why you need 0 V ? What is the dynamic range of your circuit? Maybe show us the "original" circuit. The Wheatstone Bridge can be driven by a bipolar supply as well. But then you will need bipolar supply for your amplifier.

Comment: You're not concerned at all about a differential op amp.  You're not using one.

Comment: Thanks stowoda, I've added the orignal circuit to my OP (last picture). For the offset, I assume this would be a small value? I'm trying to measure a very small change in resistance to one of the resistors in the bridge (strain gauge) which the Op Amp will amplify but the MCU can't receive above 5 V so I need to get Vout as low as possible (not necessarily 0). I think I can compensate for offset assuming it's fairly low (< 0.1, 0.2?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LM358 (like other op-amps in that similar range) has the ability to pull-down its output to close to 0 volts because it uses a 50 uA current sink on the output. Without that current sink, the minimum output voltage would be about 0.6 volts above the negative rail (0 volts in your example): -

[image]

And here comes the problem; your feedback resistor is acting like a pull-up resistor to 2.5 volts (set by R2 and Rg) and this negates the effectiveness of the internal 50 uA current sink because Rf will try and inject 250 uA into the output pin thus lifting it up above 0 volts.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there some way I can prevent Rf from behaving as a "pull-up resistor" for my purposes? I'm not sure I fully understand what current-sinks are and how to deal with them

Comment: @p.chives you could load the output with (say) 1 kohm to your ground (the negative rail) in order to reduce that offset down to something more reasonable like 30 mV but you will struggle to get closer than 5 mV. If you are intent on getting close to 0 volts then add a negative supply. Not even "so-called" rail-to-rail op-amps can get their outputs very close to either power rail.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the 1k ohm resistor on Vout and it seemed like it was working. I also tried increasing Rf and Rg (keeping R1 = R2 = 1k ohm) and found that Vout "shrunk" but then seemed to scale somewhat reliably with the resistors (Rf = Rg = 560k ohm was about 6 times larger than Rf = Rg = 100k ohm). Is this because the larger resistors also cancel this unwanted current and therefore I'm not getting the "pull up resistor" behaviour?
edit: when using the larger resistors for Rf=Rg I didn't use the 1k ohm ground on Vout*

Comment: The larger resistors will pull-up less current so this helps but beware of excessive gain if Rf and Rg are too high. Also beware of raising +Vin too high because you will hit problems with the +Vin input being too high given the limited positive supply rail. And finally, after making any value changes please ensure you have signal input-output linearity; it's dead easy to convince yourself the output is fine but it could be stuck at close to 0 volts because of a value error or too much gain (input offset voltage effect).

Answer (score -1):

lm358 need operating voltage +-16 ( 32 volt) so Arduino can supply just 5 volt so you need an op-amp operating voltage up to 5 volt

Comment: According to the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snosbt3j/snosbt3j.pdf) the min supply voltage is 3V or ±1.5V.