# Reading differential signals

Tags: differential

By the circuit shown bellow I wanna read the ripple current by the 0.33 resistor and the ripple voltage of the capacitor by adding a low pass filter to reduce the spikes and a high pass filter to extract the AC part of the capacitor's voltage. Now my question is how I'm supposed to read the differential voltage shown with the blue indicators and add off-set to it as the ground of the circuit is different from the differential pair's. Because of the set up of the system I cant read the voltage between the capacitor and ground.[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to measure the voltage or how to interpret the measurement?

Comment: I wanna read the voltage by the ADC

Comment: Depending on your ADC you may be able to do direct differential measurements (this is ideal).  Otherwise you could measure one point and then the other, although with an AC signal the time difference could be important.  If you can sample at a much higher speed than the AC frequency then this may be small enough to ignore.  Perhaps it would be better to have two ADCs and trigger conversions simultaneously.

Comment: It would be better to phrase your question purely as a question. Do not include your assumptions about the problem within the question. State the problem you see as clearly as possible and then ask a direct question.

Answer (score 0):

> *how I'm supposed to read the differential voltage shown with the blue
> indicators*

Use an op-amp configured as a differential amplifier: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/404079/cant-balance-differential-amplifier-circuit).

You may need to create a small negative voltage for the op-amp negative rail or, if you choose your op-amp carefully (inputs capable of working close to 0 volts on your schematic), you should be good to go.

Another thing to think about is the frequency of the ripple you are trying to measure; because your circuit is a boost converter, it will be running at (probably) several tens of kHz so, choose an op-amp with reasonable bandwidth in order to measure your signal without high frequency attenuation.

If you need the ripple voltage centred at some DC offset suitable for your ADC, the ground connection of resistor \$R_g\$ above can be changed to that offset voltage because \$V_{out}\$ is referenced to that voltage.

Comment: I did the exact thing as you mentioned but I had problem with the negative voltage and through simulation and adding negative supply I had an unwanted offset on my signal. Is there any way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: Numbers, numbers, numbers. Microvolts, millivolts or volts? @عرفانمیرحسینی

Comment: the output voltage is about 100 mv

Comment: Well @عرفانمیرحسینی I can only tell you that maybe you mis-connected your circuit or tried to engineer too-high a gain using an op-amp with poor input offset voltage specifications. Using a diff amp (as per my answer) is a tried and tested way of achieving what you want.

Comment: @عرفانمیرحسینی if we're done here you should probably consider formally accepting an answer or raise another comment if there is still something you need clarification on.